# how to solve this with kmeans clustering and use cosine similiraty

Tags: database, listview, k-means

can anyone tell to me how k-means clustering working on textmining..
and i using cosine similarity as the distance metric.

```
nim              310910022       320910044          310910043           310910021
access               0               2                  3                   5
abdi                 1               0                  0                   0 
actual               5               0                  0                   1
arrow                 0               1                 1                   2
```

this data is on listview

How can I do that in VB.net? to get any cluster and trending topic of the term ?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

First I would separate the problem into two parts:

1. Computing the k-means clustering assignments
2. Getting the data from the GUI (you mention the data is on a listview)

I assume 2 is straight forward and you just need help on 1.

I would start by re-writing the code to just read a TSV text file of the data as you specified. This will make things a lot easier to debug.

Then ask if you want to implement the kmeans algorithm yourself or use a library.
If you want to implement it, here is a link to the pseudo code
http://www.scribd.com/doc/89373376/K-Means-Pseudocode
You can also search up other kmeans pseudocode.

If you want to use a library to just "run" your data against a kmeans algorithm, here is one example in python/scipy.
http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/04/k-means-clustering-with-scipy.html

Regardless of which approach you use, realize that kmeans is non-deterministic and you may get different answers everytime you run it. I would recommend computing against a known validation set to see if the data is roughly what you think it should be.

Comment: can i use this library on vb.net ?

Comment: You can re-write the pseudo code in vb.net but you can't easily run the python library in vb.net. Why not separate your application into two parts: the GUI in vb.net and computing clustering part in R or Python?